# How to pass executable wrapper generated by java_binary to ctx.actions.run

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to understand best practices regarding the `java_binary`. So, if I have a code something like:

```
java_binary(
  name = "my-runner",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
  main_class = "my.awesome.package.MyRunner",
)
```

When I'm running `bazel build MyMainClass` - everything works fine - I can see two files generated - a jar file and a wrapper script.

According to [official documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary):

> Using the wrapper script is preferred to java -jar because it also
>   passes the JVM flags and the options to load native libraries.

And here's come the problem I'm failing to resolve - how exactly I'm supposed to access that wrapper script?

What I've tried is:

```
some_rule = rule(
    _some_rule_impl,
    attrs = {
        "_executable": attr.label(
           cfg = "host",
           executable = True,
           default=":my-runner"
        ),
        ...
    }
  )
```

and in `_some_rule_impl` I'm trying to pass the executable to `ctx.actions.run` - and I'm getting an error that attribute must produce a single file.

When I'm passing `my-runner_deploy_deploy.jar` as a file that I can pass to java - everything works. However I wonder how to pass wrapper as executable.

Answer (score 0):

In the run action, you can use `executable = ctx.executable._executable`.

The documentation for [ctx.actions.run](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#run) gives this example https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/master/rules/actions_run/execute.bzl

*Edit* I think there is some confusion: `:my-runner` is a java_binary with the wrapper script already.

Comment: yes, of course I can, the problem is I'm failing to point to wrapper script - I'm getting "the attribute must produce a single file"  and can not find any doc or examples where exactly wrapper script from java_binary is uses in run action

Comment: You want `default=":my-runner"`, not `default=":my-runner_deploy"` I think

Comment: sorry it was a typo - it's my-runner and it's not working - this is exactly what this question is about (